# How to use Method reference for FileFilter with getName().endsWith()

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, filefilter

I have a lambda expression of type FileFilter that returns true for all files ending with .java -

```
FileFilter lambdaFilter = (File pathname) -> pathname.getName().endsWith(".java");
```

I want to use Method reference for above expression. My unsuccessful attempt -

```
FileFilter lambdaFilter = File::getName.endsWith(".java");
```

Is it possible to use Method Reference for above case? How?

Comment: No, you can't do that here. Whenever the target of method reference is the result of a call chain, you know that you can't use a method reference directly, unless you can somehow compose those transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do chaining this way

```
.map(File::getName).map(name -> name.endsWith(".java"))
```

But not in a single operation